# vector space intersection and sum

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $U, W$ be subspaces of $V$ such that $U \subset W$. Show that there is a subspace $X$ of $V$ such that $W \cap X = U$ and $W + X = V$.
How can I solve it from the basis of the subspace?

Comment: You could look at the quotient space $V/W$, if you're familiar with that.

Comment: thank you! but can you give me more hint?

Comment: Take a basis of $V/W$ and lift it to $V$. Together with $U$ this spans a space $X$ with the desired properties. This comes down to the same construction as given in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\beta=\left\{u_1, \dots , u_k\right\}$ be a basis of $U$. Since $U\subset W$, we can extend this to a basis $\beta'=\left\{u_1, \dots, u_k, w_{k+1},\dots w_l \right\}$ of $W$. And again we can extend this to a basis $$\alpha=\left\{u_1, \dots, u_k, w_{k+1},\dots w_l, v_{l+1}, \dots v_n\right\}$$
of $V$.

Now define $X=\text{span}(u_1, \dots, u_k,v_{l+1}, \dots v_n)$. This space does the job. Indeed, since $W=\text{span}(w_{k+1},\dots w_l)$, we have that $W+X=\text{span}(u_1, \dots, u_k, w_{k+1},\dots w_l, v_{l+1}, \dots v_n)$ and $W\cap X=\text{span}(u_1, \dots, u_k)$.

**Remark:** Compare the strategy of this proof to the proof of the dimension theorem for subspaces. Notice how being able to choose bases of a certain form can simplify these types of arguments.